# Structure not recognizing a member for some reason

Tags: c++, struct

When run this code, it gives me a strange error. I have a class called scene, and scene has an array member called "commands". I have a struct called cGame, which has a member called current scene.

```
struct MainGameLoop{
    void init(){
        this->cGame.init(); 
    }

    game_struct cGame; 

    void begin_cipher(string input){
        if(input == "save" || input == "SAVE"){
            cGame.cPlayer.save_game(); 
            cout << "\n\nGame saved..."; 
        }

        if(input == "back" || input == "BACK"){
            cGame.go_back();
        }

        if(input != "back" && input != "BACK" && input != "save" && input != "SAVE"){
            bool is_recognized_scene_command; 
            for(int c = 0; c < 11 ; c++){
                if(input == cGame.scene_container[this->cGame.current_scene].commands[c]){
                    cout << "\n\nREQUEST IS RECOGNIZED BY SCENE...";
                } 
                else{
                    cout << "REQUEST IS NOT RECOGNIZED!"; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This code gives the error :

```
279 C:\Dev-Cpp\the_main_mage.cpp no match for 'operator[]' in '((MainGameLoop*)this)->MainGameLoop::cGame.game_struct::scene_container[((MainGameLoop*)this)->MainGameLoop::cGame.game_struct::current_scene]'
```

Comment: Why would you ever put your main loop in a struct? This isn't Java/ C#, you know?

Comment: could you provide the struct definition for the type of `game_struct::scene_container[]` (and for that matter, you might as well include `game_struct` and `scene_container`)

Comment: I don't implement operator. It just says that for some reason...

Comment: That is the type of field `scene_container` in `cGame` ?

Comment: what is the type of `game_struct::current_scene` ?

Comment: It would help to add the definition of `game_struct` as well as the offending line 279 from `the_main_mage.cpp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is about `scene_container`. Are you sure this is an array/vector/... that can be indexed with `[]`? Is `current_scene` the correct type to be used as an index?

Comment: It is. It is an array of 10 scenes. I access it using the current scene member.